# is IPad accelerometer normalized to gravity

Tags: ios, accelerometer, uiaccelerometer

While porting my Android app to iOS I was confused with one thing, so I want to find out: am I right or mo code works wrong. At Android device accelerometer returns values in physical measure units: m/s2.  On ipad i get summary force approximately = 1.0 for still device(and i expect 9.8). My first explanation is that  returning value is normalized to 9.8, so I must  multiply it with 9.8 to get real force. My second idea - my code is totally wrong, but it's hard to believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Docs on CMAcceleration:

```
CMAcceleration
The type of a structure containing 3-axis acceleration values.

typedef struct {
      double x;
      double y;
      double z;
} CMAcceleration;
```

> X-axis acceleration in G's (gravitational force).
>   Y-axis acceleration in G's (gravitational force).
>   Z-axis acceleration in G's (gravitational force).

**A G is a unit of gravitation force equal to that exerted by the earth’s gravitational field (9.81 m s−2).**

Comment: so the values i get on x y and z such as 0.998 includes gravity? actually I have a maths equation which requires acceleration on x axis... shall I user 0.998 or 0.998 * 9.8 ??